# Multiple assignment in module.exports?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Watching along with a tutorial video for Mongodb modelling using mongoose, and the instructor sets up a user model and includes the following line after creating the schema

```
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

My main question is on how multiple assignment like this is possible. How would this line be different from

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: I don't think that those two examples are different, it's just something that's allowed in JavaScript.

Comment: Yep! for example, I do this all the time `const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose')`. The `mongoose` imports everything and the `{ Schema }` destructures the one property from from that value. Same concept above, except it's a "straight" copy. i.e `const a = b = 2`; so both `a` and `b` are `2`

Comment: Both are same and allowed in javascript